# User geolocation - case study

Tags: django, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

We have a Django app which stores information about places around the world.
The case is, we want to use geolocation (any method) to locate visitors' location and then show places near them using Google maps.

I am looking for advice on best practices how to achieve this. I have in mind that not all browsers support geolocation and, even if it is supported, users may decline geolocation permission.

**I was thinking about a scenerio such as this:**

- new user visits our website
- we ask for geolocation permission (if browser supports it)
- if user gives us permission - we query database for nearby places
- if user declines geolocation - we use geo-IP data to get position

However, in addition to this, immediately after user visit website, I want to center map on his position, then via AJAX request load places near to them.

Do you have any suggestion, how to locate user even on older-browser? Maybe my conception is wrong?

Comment: You can ask the user to enter their postcode and get a googlemaps location from that. (This is a good option to provide anyway, geo-IP data can often be inaccurate

Comment: When do you suggest to ask for a postcode? Before asking for HTML5 geolocation? Before?

Comment: Can you not just have a postcode box available above the map at all times? You can still ask for geolocation automatically, but if it fails or they decline, you have a fallback option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your concept is not wrong. You are heading in the right direction, just needs some refinement:

1. New user visit our website
2. we use geo-IP data to get position
3. We show Google Map with user's position centered on the map (using IP)
4. we ask for geolocation permission (if browser supports it)
5. if the user accepts permission we center the map to the new
   location
6. we query database for near places (using either browser geolocation), using either geo-IP in case of (decline permission or lack of browser support) or location from geolocation.

You can also add (5.5 step) using Peter Tinkler's suggestion to ask for location in case the browser doesn't support geolocation. (Though not everyone knows their postal code, so you need to ask for free text like nearest intersection, especially useful if you are on the go). This is also useful in case you want to search for things not exactly where you are now